# Can't solve floating point exception in c++

Tags: c++

This is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
   int polski;
   int wf;
   int matma;
}oceny;

int funkcja_liczaca(int suma, int ile_liczb, int ktory_przedmiot, oceny &temporary);

int main()
{
   int suma = 0;
   int temp[3];
   int ile_liczb_zostalo_wprowadzonych = 0;
   oceny database;
   string teksty[3] = {"polski: ", "wf: ", "matma: "};
   for (int i=0; i!=3; i++)
   {
      cout << teksty[i] << endl;
      while(temp[i]!=0)
      {
         cin >> temp[i];
         if(cin.good()) //floating point exception here. the code don't even step into this one.
         {
            {
               suma = temp[i] + suma;
               ile_liczb_zostalo_wprowadzonych++;
               if(temp[i]==0){ile_liczb_zostalo_wprowadzonych--;}
            }
         }else cout << "error";
      };
      funkcja_liczaca(suma, ile_liczb_zostalo_wprowadzonych, i, database);
      suma = 0;
      ile_liczb_zostalo_wprowadzonych = 0;
   }
   cout << "output of struct members in main() \n";
   cout << database.polski << endl;
   cout << database.wf << endl;
   cout << database.matma << endl;
   return 0;
}

int funkcja_liczaca(int suma, int ile_liczb, int ktory_przedmiot, oceny &temporary)
{
   if(ktory_przedmiot==0){temporary.polski=suma/ile_liczb;cout << temporary.polski << endl;}
   if(ktory_przedmiot==1){temporary.wf=suma/ile_liczb;cout << temporary.wf << endl;}
   if(ktory_przedmiot==2){temporary.matma=suma/ile_liczb;cout << temporary.matma << endl;}
}
```

It counts arithmetic average of inputed numbers untill user input 0 which ends loop. then the arithmetic average of thoose numbers is counted in the funkcja_liczaca() and it's saved into the members of struct oceny.
everything works fine but i want to implement something like "stream" check while inputing from keyboard to prevent inputing bad variables into integer type variable.
so inputing 'g' into temp[i] is causing floating point exception. the question is why? cin.good() and cin.fail() is not working.

Comment: Please add sample input, expected output, and observed output.

Comment: input can be every integer number except 0 becouse it cause running funkcja_liczaca() function. i want to protect input stream aganist wrong types. ie: when user provide 'g' or any other character instead of integer into temp[i]  then the error message should be outputed. But it cause floating point exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to deal with errors in the input stream, it's better to read the input line by line as a string and then attempt to extract your data from the string. If extraction of the data from the string is successful, proceed to process the data. Otherwise, attempt to read the next line of text. Here's the core logic for that.

```
  while ( true )
  {
     cout << teksty[i] << endl;
     std::string line;
     if ( !getline(cin, line) )
     {
        // Problem reading a line of text.
        // Exit.
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

     // Construct a istringstream object to extract the data.
     std::istringstream istr(line);
     if ( istr >> temp[i] )
     {
        // Extracting the number was successful.
        // Add any additional checks as necessary.
        // Break out of the while loop.
        break.
     }

     // Bad input. Continue to the next iteration of the loop
     // and read the next line of text.
  }
```